# Using ValidationRule to validate values in WPF is stopping setting values in textboxes if they are not correct and retaining the last correct value

Tags: wpf, mvvm, validationrules

I'm using validationrule class to validate my textbox values against length. It works fine and show the error also if it is invalid but the problem is if users are editing the textbox it is not storing the value and does not even call set.

I want to have the the values whatever user is entering in textbox even if it is valid or not. Is there a way to get through this.

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            string valueToValidate = value as string;
            if ((MinLength > 0 || MaxLength >0) && (valueToValidate.Length < MinLength || valueToValidate.Length > MaxLength))
            { 
                return new ValidationResult(false, $"The field lentgh should be between: {MinLength}-{MaxLength} characters.");
            }
            else if(APIKeyLength>0 &&(valueToValidate.Length != APIKeyLength))
                return new ValidationResult(false, $"The field lentgh should be 36 characters");

            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
```

And in xml it is like:

```
<Binding Path="ClientID" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <advancedConfigurationPage:ClientIDValidationRule MinLength="8" MaxLength="100"/>
```

</Binding.ValidationRules>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `ValidationStep` property of the `ValidationRule` to `UpdatedValue` will cause it to run *after* the source property has been set;

```
<advancedConfigurationPage:ClientIDValidationRule MinLength="8" MaxLength="100"
                                                  ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
```

Comment: This helps to hit set property but in this case validation does not work. valueToValidate is always null

Comment: I was able to get the values using below expresson. Thanks
((Application.AdvanceViewModel)((BindingExpression)value).DataItem).ClientID